# WAMP and BrowserSync when XDebug outputs errors

Tags: browser, gruntjs, wamp, synchronization, xdebug

I have WAMP installed and it has XDebug showing me PHP errors in the browser.
I also use [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) with Grunt to have the page reloaded when there are changes in the code. So, I have this kind of PHP file:

```
<?php

    bad_code_here

    echo "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body></body></html>";

?>
```

The problem is that BrowserSync will not automatically refresh the page when there are PHP errors. BrowserSync needs a `<head>` and `<body>` tags, where a JavaScript for refreshing the page is inserted. XDebug doesn't create such tags, so, if there are fatal errors the page will not be refreshed after I correct them.

In order to fix this I wonder if I can:

- change the template used by XDebug in such a way that there will always be a `<head>` and `<body>` tag. I cannot find the HTML files used by XDebug. Is this possible?
- make my code generate such tags but only when there are errors (I don't know if PHP provides such an option, of saying: anytime the code fails generate this header and HTML)

Are there any other options?

Comment: Dare I ask what is wrong with the F5 key?

Comment: I have dual monitors and I have managed to make it work. It is more comfortable and time saving to just make changes in one monitor and see them auto-reload on the other one. CSS is injected, which means the page doesn't even reload, only has its layout and style updated. With a single monitor you still have to change windows but with 2 it is really cool. By the way, I managed to disable XDebug and create my own error handlers in PHP.